# Cannot access Tomcat server in local network from mobile phone

Tags: android, tomcat, mobile, connection

I have a local Tomcat (http) server running inside a local network through ethernet and since I have got a new phone I have not been able to access it (via WiFi).

On my old phone, a Lenovo P2, it was working just like normal, but now that I have a Huawei P9 Lite I get ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE when trying to access the server from the phone. I can, however, access the server normally using another phone.

Is there some kind of network setting I need to alter on the Huawei P9 Lite? I have not been able to figure it out yet.

Comment: if you are accessing tomcat server from your local system you need to connect your device in same network connected to your system

Comment: Check your phone proxy, if it's ok open port 80 in your firewall

Comment: You did not tell what type of connection you use. Should we guess?

Comment: @GaneshPatil This was my initial thought as well, but it isn't the problem.

Comment: @greenapps Local company network, using ethernet on the server and wifi on the device. Server uses http protocol.

Comment: @HamedNabizadeh Proxy is OK, firewall is off for private networks.

Comment: Try this [link](http://www.mobitechie.com/android-2/how-to-access-localhost-on-android-over-wifi/)

Comment: @HamedNabizadeh As I stated, the firewall is off so allowing port 80 will not make any difference. Also, I doubt if the problem is in the server as it is reachable from other devices.

Comment: OK, Remove "address=" from Connector string in your configuration file and restart Tomcat or listen tomcat to your ip address in the Connector string

Comment: No use. I just tried to access the XAMPP landing page as well, but I couldn't access that page either. So the problem isn't in Tomcat I think?

Comment: Try with a browser on your device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so for some reason DHCP got me a different network address on my device. I had to statically allocate the correct network address and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows Firewall does often provide or block access based on application, not just port, temporarily or completely disable your firewall:

Running the following as an **Administrator** Command Shell:

```
netsh firewall set opmode mode = disable
```

Comment: I don't think this will be helping, as the server is accessible from other devices inside the network. So the problem is the device, not the server.

Comment: is your local server and device configured in same network ?

Comment: Yes.

And for some reason I have extend this message.

Comment: But for that you need static ip address for your network.. make it static

Comment: Yes, I found out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From windows 10, all i had to do was to make the network "PRIVATE" instead of PUBLIC. Strange but works, if you make it public, windows rule makes the network hidden from external connection by default